# Make complex form appear "disappeared" using dashes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, icon, stroke, illustration

I'm currently new into Adobe Illustrator and I'm having quite a bit a stroke when it comes to icon design.

I'm mostly using icons from flaticon, in this case, I'm using an icon of a can, a package and a fruit ([Source](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/canned-vegetables_99941#term=canned%20food&page=2&position=91)).

[image: Screenshot of original icon from flaticon]

Now I'm trying to make it look disappeared / gone. I'm trying to achieve something similar like this (found via Google [here](https://www.istockphoto.com/ae/vector/missing-father-silhouette-gm470120262-62251146)):

[image: Father gone sample image]

Now what I achieved is to make a border appear dashed just like I wanted. But this did not fit my needs, as I do not have a border on this, but this is rather a complex form which is filled with color, instead of having a border:

[image: Right click on the can part of the icon, showing it's only a form without border]

How would I achieve the same result (converting this into a line and make it dashed) as in the picture above, without having to make every dash by myself by applying a cut mask?

Thank you in advance for helping a beginner out! :-)

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that your question shows some *effort*: tell us what you already know and understood; show us what you tried and failed; document what you found when searching the Internet or manual. As applicable, illustrate your question with sketches, screenshots or examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is an icon which has been converted from line to shape. Which means you will have to find a not-converted icon or redraw the lines yourself manually to be then able to apply a dashed style to the line (aka: stroke).

Once you have an actual line shape, you can apply a dashed line via 'Window → Stroke' and play with the numbers in red highlight below.

There is no automatic conversion from object to line. There may be some combination of advanced tricks to give you a partial result, but that won't be easy and some manual work will still be needed for a perfect conversion.

[image]